# Capitalize the first letter of every word in a string in s

Tags: c

I would like to make the first letter of a word upper case but i end up changing the entire string.Any Help!

```
{
   //Prompt for the name
   char *s  = GetString(); /* some function that returns a string */

   //capitalize
   for(int i = 0,n = strlen(s);i < n;i++)
   {
      printf("%c",toupper(s[0]));
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `string s  = GetString();` is not standard C.

Comment: `string` - What is this datatype in C?

Comment: Just look at your code, and **think** about what it does. Step though it line by line in your head. You'll quickly realize it makes no sense.

Comment: To be even more explicit; the language does  not make sense. `string` and `GetString` are not standard C; yet `printf` is in C invalidating C# and C++ perhaps. You need to guide us more.

Comment: Just use `s[0]=toupper(s[0])`

Comment: Maybe **string** is declared like this 

( #define string char* ) :P

Comment: @RatulSharker, it may. Or it may be `typedef void* string;` for some crazy string handling library, or it can be a macro or an extension, or just not plain `c`. We can't know, so the OP must clarify.

Comment: I think `GetString()` and `string` are from the ever so popular [`cs50.h` header](http://mirror.cs50.net/library50/c/cs50-library-c-3.0/cs50.h), which seems to crop up every now and then here.

Comment: @MOehm, that include starts with `typedef char *string;`. Also the use of `strlen` and `toupper(s[0])` implies it is a `char *`. He's also tagged it `C` and not `C#` or `C++` so I think we can conclude he just forgot the include or a `typedef`. I am going to edit it on that basis.

Answer (score 6):

How about the following:

```
void
capitalise(char *s)
{
     int start = 1;
     for (; *s; s++)
     {
          if (start)
              *s = toupper(*s);
          start = isspace(*s);
     }
}
```

As you are passing `s` to `strlen`, I presume it is in fact a `char *`, and that `string` is some strange `typedef` you have not told us about.

Note I use `toupper()` and `isspace()` rather than looking directly at the `char` values. This means it will handle starts of words after (e.g.) tabs, and provided locale is set right, it will convert (for instance) `é` to `É`.